# How to display values of excel file in a web page

Tags: python, mysql, web, flask

I have excel files (tab-delimited) and the contents of which I want to display in a web page.

Sample dataset:

```
Group A Group B Group C Group D Group E Group F
lynx    cat zeus    zebra   smug    zebra
zebra   lump    flun    flun    kilm    lump
    zebra   cat
```

I want to display links to datasets in the first page:

```
link:<Dataset 1>
link:<Dataset 2>
link:<Dataset 3>
```

So, for example when the link to "Dataset 1" is clicked, I want to display a drop-down list:

```
Group A 
Group B
Group C
Group D
Group E
Group F
```

Then, if Group A is selected, the content of that column, lynx and zebra, should be displayed.

What is the best and quickest way to get these datasets on a web page? Can I also get away with not using a database and a web server for this purpose and just get data displayed in a web browser?

Comment: I feel you're missing something here.... There can be no (live - over the internet) web page without a web server.

Comment: Thanks Dhruv, I wondered if there is an option of not displaying the data live, but just an app that will load the data in a web browser.

Comment: Python or any other server side language could do that. Although to run those programs as web-pages on a local machine, you'd still need their specific environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a python script to produce a **static** HTML files for each data set and for the main data set index.

For each dataset, you can use [tabulate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate) to create a table in an HTML format and save it to an HTML file.
For the main index, you can use [tabulate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate) again to create an HTML table of the different datasets.

### For the datasets

Parse the data and headers from the files and write it into an HTML table.

```py
def parse_file(file):
    with open(file, "r") as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        headers = reader.fieldnames
        table = []
        for row in reader:
            table.append([row[h] for h in headers]])
    return table, headers

from tabulate import tabulate
datasets = {}
for f in files:
    table, headers = parse_file(f)
    t = tabulate(table, headers, tablefmt="html")
    html_filename = "%s.html" % f
    data_sets[f] = html_filename
    with open(html_filename, "w") as f:
        f.write(t)
```

- table should be a list of lists. Each inner list is a line in the table.
- headers should be the list of headers of each column.

## For the index file

```py
table = []
for f in files:
    table.append(["<a href='%s'>%s</a>" % (datasets[f], f)])
t = tabulate(table, tablefmt="html")
with open("index.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(t)
```

You can now open `index.html` in the browser and browse through the datasets.

Comment: Thanks so much @Liran Funaro. I tried your solution but have problem displaying the contents of individual dataset. The index page was okay and I could see the links to each dataset, but after clicking each dataset, nothing was displayed. I made some changes and will show the code below.

Comment: def parse_file(file):
 with open("Dataset1.csv", "r") as f:
  reader = csv.DictReader(f)
  headers =  reader.fieldnames
  #headers = reader.next()
  rows = []
  for row in reader:
   table = rows.append(row) 
  #table = [row for row in reader]
  return table, headers

Comment: I wrote the above parse_file funcion and also added this line: files=glob.glob('*.csv'). Perhaps something was wrong with my function.

Comment: The csv.DictReader returns each row as `dict`. You should have to convert it to a list first. I've added the corrected `parse_file(file)` code to my answer.

Comment: Thanks so much! It works now. Though I got an error: NameError: name 'h' is not defined. So changed the line: table.append([row[h] for j in headers]) to table.append([row[col] for col in headers]).